# promises not executing sequentially javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the piece of code below executing using promises.The problem I have is that the promise is not executing sequentially by waiting for the first block to execute before proceeding to the next block

below is the code:

```
array[]

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
//userarray is some array with user id's
userarray.forEach(function(entry) {

    User.findOne({ user_id: entry}, function(err, user) {
       if (err) throw err;
        console.log(user.name);
        array.push(user.name);      
    });
  });
  resolve("success");
})
.then(function() {  
 console.log(array);
 console.log("done");
});
```

below is the output

> [] //array is still empty
>
> done
>
> tom
>
> dick
>
> harry

when what i want is

> tom
>
> dick
>
> harry
>
> ["tom", "dick", "harry"]
>
> done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like `User.findOne` will call its callback asynchronously so that your promise is resolved before the callbacks are actually invoked. You can try something like this:

```
var promises = userarray.map(function(entry) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    User.findOne({ user_id: entry}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      console.log(user.name); 
      resolve(user.name);
    });
  });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(array) {  
  console.log(array);
  console.log("done");
});
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I was in the process of writing a similar solution when you beat me to it 

Comment: You actually don't need this `array.push` stuff, just do `resolve(user)`

Comment: @georg, yes, I missed that. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This is the right general structure.  It would be better to create a wrapper around `User.findOne()` that returns a promise or use the promises capabilities built into the database so all the logic flow is promise-based and so you have a promise interface for `.findOne()` to use elsewhere in your code (reusable code).  Also, Bluebird's `Promise.map()` is made exactly for this situation.

Comment: Making the three `User.findOne` calls in parallel does not guarantee that the three responses will come back in the right order, therefore the individual names could log as eg "dick", "tom", "harry". On the other hand, `Promise.all(promises)` *will* deliver the expected `array` comprising `["tom", "dick", harry]` regardless of the timing of the responses.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 The code in the OP does not guarantee order of callbacks either, does it?

Comment: Correct, we know the OP's code has issue. But he finishes off by stating what he wants. This answer may or may not deliver its output in the expected order.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 IMHO, what OP is really asking for is that "done" comes after the promise being completed. It does not make too much sense to me to guarantee the order of results of several independent asynchronous process. Even if ordered result is needed, it could be done by sorting after having all results instead of blocking each other during the asynchronous computation process, right?

Comment: @LifuHuang, I expect you are right but we don't know for certain. My original comment was designed to warn him about the order of responses in case it matters to him.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 That's true, thanks for the information ;)

Comment: Hi @LifuHuang, thanks for your solution but for  some weird reason , this doesn't seem to work as expected. I still get "done" logged  before the array and array items...i have no idea why this is so,,,

Comment: @Roamer-1888, for  some weird reason , this doesn't seem to work as expected. I still get "done" logged  before the array and array items...i have no idea why this is so,,,

Comment: @ali The array is still empty?

Comment: @LifuHuang yes, the array is empty when it is logged, seems like the console.log(array) bit is executed before the first process finishes executing

Comment: @ali, you are doing something wrong.  Providing `User.findOne()` executes its callback, Lifu's code should work. [Here's a mockup](https://jsfiddle.net/0z6qxdah/).

Comment: @LifuHuang,well, I have tried the suggestions and for some reason i'm not able to resolve the issue. if you don't mind, I have put up the actual code [here](https://pastebin.com/hW51qt2L) and the model file [here](https://pastebin.com/BeF9Ds1W).if it's not much trouble, could you point out what i'm doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, well, I have tried the suggestions and for some reason i'm not able to resolve the issue. if you don't mind, I have put up the actual code [here](https://pastebin.com/hW51qt2L) and the model file [here](https://pastebin.com/BeF9Ds1W).if it's not much trouble, could you point out what i'm doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: @ali that's simply because you invoked resolve() before the task actually being done. You need to pass the resolve function into the pushOdds, and invoke it from the promise handlers inside pushOdds after your work is actually done.

Comment: @ali, several things need fixing, chief amongst which are (1) purge the `odds` array; (2) in `pushOdds()`, instead of pushing `pred` onto `odds`, return a promise that delivers `pred`; (3) in `out.map(function(){...})`, remove `new Promise()` and `resolve()` in favour of `return pushOdds(...)`. With all that in place, `Promise.all()` will deliver the desired `odds` array to its callback. I can't write this as an answer because it's not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 , sorry I do not follow how to implement this, and my daftness is on full display now. i just started using promises and I don't think I've fully grasped how they work-totally confused now.i know it's too much to ask for but could you show me how to implement this in the code, how to pass resolve into another function into to achieve this? or do I have to ask another question on SO?thanks.

Comment: @LifuHuang, sorry I do not follow how to implement this, and my daftness is on full display now. i just started using promises and I don't think I've fully grasped how they work-totally confused now.i know it's too much to ask for but could you show me how to implement this in the code, how to pass resolve into another function into to achieve this? or do I have to ask another question on SO?thanks.

Comment: @ali, I modified your code a bit and put it [here](https://pastebin.com/VxkD4TMU). Didn't have chance to verify its correctness, but hope it demonstrates the basic idea.

Comment: thanks a lot @LifuHuang, works perfectly--sending some good karma your way :-) thanks again..will follow the code to understand promises better.

Comment: @ali glad it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not really elegant but should get the job done.

```
var length = userarray.length;
userarray.forEach(function(entry) {

    User.findOne({ user_id: entry}, function(err, user) {
       if (err) throw err;
        console.log(user.name);
        array.push(user.name);  
        if(!--length) resolve("success");
    });
  });
})
```